# An interesting inequality about polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, inequality, polynomials

Let $P=\sum_0^n a_n x^n$ be a polynomial with degree$\leq n$, prove that
\begin{equation}
|P(0)|\lesssim_{n}\int_{-1}^{1} |P(x)| dx
\end{equation}
(where $A\lesssim_{n}B$ means $A\leq C_{n}B$ for some constant $C_{n}$)

It may be easier to describe coefficients using integral for trigonometric polynomial, so I consider $\sum_0^n a_n(\cos \theta)^n$. Because of the orthogonal property, we get $a_0=\int_0^{2\pi} P(\cos \theta) d\theta$. After changing of variable, it's not hard to see $|a_0|\lesssim_{n} \frac{1}{\delta}\int_{-(1-\delta)}^{1-\delta}|P(x)| dx+\delta\max_{1-\delta\leq |x|\leq 1|} |P(x)|$, so we get $|P(0)|\lesssim_{n}(\int_{-1}^{1} |P(x)| dx)^{\frac{1}{2}}(\int_{-1}^{1} |P'(x)| dx)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

I don't know how to proceed. Maybe there are some other methods? (maybe complex analysis?)

Comment: what does $\lesssim_{n}$ mean?

Comment: @NN2: I guess that it means that there is a constant $C$ that depend on $n$ s.t. $|P(0)|\leq\int_{-1}^1|P(x)|\,\mathrm d x$. (-1 to not give a clear statement and not define every notations).

Comment: Sorry,I have explained the vague notation.

Comment: I would say that you have not explained the notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $P_n$ be the space of polynomials of degree no larger than $n$. Check that $$||P||=\int_{-1}^1|P|$$is a norm on $P_n$. Now define a linear functional $\Lambda$ on $P_n$ by $$\Lambda P=P(0),$$and use the fact that any linear functional on a finite-dimensional normed vector space is continuous, ie bounded.

Comment: Thank you,It's a beautiful solution which show me the advantages of soft analysis.